# How to fetch data by giving page URL in Wikidata Query Service (SPARQL)

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to get some lists of data from Wikipedia. So I am using Wikidata SPARQL query service. What I need to know is how can I fetch the data from the `URL (Wikipedia page URL)`. Currently I am searching from `name`. Following is my query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?birthLocation ?birthLocationLabel WHERE {
  ?item (wdt:P31|wdt:P101|wdt:P106)/wdt:P279* wd:Q482980 ;
        rdfs:label "Enid Blyton"@en ;
        wdt:P19 ?birthLocation
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

I need to search by URL instead of name. How can I achieve this? And also is that possible to get the sub links from the URL. I tried by I couldn't find any way to get them. So anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong here? I highly appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?birthLocation ?birthLocationLabel WHERE {
  <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enid_Blyton> schema:about ?item .
  
  ?item wdt:P19 ?birthLocation
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser It's working perfectly. Thank you very much. If you can post this as an answer. I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: @UninformedUser And also how can I get the URL again as article field?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?url ?item ?itemLabel ?birthLocation ?birthLocationLabel
WHERE { 
  VALUES ?url { <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enid_Blyton>}
  ?url schema:about ?item . 
  ?item wdt:P19 ?birthLocation 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } 
}` - feel free to answer your own question if you think this query works as intended.

Comment: @UninformedUser It worked perfectly. Thank you. And yes sure I will post this as the answer.